# Symfony2 / Plesk change php.ini location

Tags: php, symfony, plesk

I'm using Plesk panel on my server, and I have to change default path to php.ini to plesk path **/opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc** in my symfony2 project. It's possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plesk's PHP binary /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php uses it's own /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.ini, not default.

If something uses default php.ini it means that you use default php binary(/usr/bin/php).

Default php binary call:

```
~# php --ini
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
```

Plesk PHP binary call:

```
~# /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php --ini
Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.ini
```

In your server command/script you can use it in that way:

```
/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php  /path/to/your/script.php
```

or in [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) of /path/to/your/script.php:

```
#!/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php
```

Maybe you just need to switch PHP handler to PHP 5.6:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer,
I know, but I need to use for my symfony2 project this PHP -> /opt/plesk/php/5.6/etc/php.ini, not default. It's possible?

Comment: Maybe you just need to switch PHP handler to PHP 5.6?

Comment: Yes, but server anyway uses php -v 5.4.16

Comment: Yes, this handler used for website. If you want to use this PHP in your server commands/scripts use this binary /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php file. like "/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php your-script.php"

Comment: Yes, but my question is: how to change path to the php.ini in symfony2 project. Somebody changed my question yesterday...

Comment: If you are running symphony's app/console you should add at the begging of console file string "#!/usr/bin/env /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php"  as described here http://www.sitepoint.com/command-line-php-using-symfony-console/

Comment: Just to be clear, first of all you should worry about which php binary file runs you project.

Comment: Thanks, it should help